# Existe como configurar um Registro de Domínio no registro.br para uma determinada pasta de uma URL?

Tags: dns

Por exemplo: Vou registrar o site www.fulanodetal.com.br e gostaria de que quando ao acessar esse dominio ele exibisse o site www.meusistema.com.br/usuario/11

Já tentei usar iframe, frameset mas sempre tenho problemas em capturar URL posteriormente, pois a url nunca muda nesses casos. Enfim, existe alguma forma de configurar isso no DNS?

Comment: Já tentou só redirecionar para o link `www.meusistema.com.br/usuario/11` ?

Comment: Para isso adicionaria uma tag no html de `www.fulanodetal.com.br`, ficando assim: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://www.meusistema.com.br/usuario/11">` após cinco segundos que acessor `www.fulanodetal.com.br` seria redirecionado para `http://www.meusistema.com.br/usuario/11`

Comment: Ola leonardo, seria uma solução, mas gostaria de oferecer aos clientes uma opção mais personalizada, sem a ideia de que ele "é o usuario 11" entende?

Comment: Hum, entendo, seria um pouco complicado, teria uma forma porém ficaria assim `usuario.meusistema.com.br`, que seria criar um registro `CNAME` no DNS com o nome do usuário e apontar ele para o ip ou nome de `www.meusistema.com.br/usuario/11` e fazer o esquema acima com o html, mas redirecionando para `usuario.meusistema.com.br`... Seria como um subdomínio de `meu sistema.com.br`.. Porém ficaria complexo pois teria que criar diversos subdomínios, uma para cada cliente e apontando para registros diferentes.Porém isso exigiria um servidor dedicado, prestadoras de hospedagem geralmente não permitem

Comment: é... nesse caso ficaria complexo mesmo pois quando o usuário se cadastra tudo é dinânico, teria q ser criado tudo automaticamente. Não vai rolar! Pra fazer o que preciso teria que ir pra Angular e pegar tudo via API, mas pra agora nao vai rolar uhauha. Bom, valeu a idéia.

Comment: já tentou usar .htaccess para "camuflar" a URL, veja: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: é verdade Pedro, pode ser uma boa ideia, almenos eu consigo dizer que o http://www.meusistema.com.br/usuario/11 será visto como http://www.meusistema.com.br/fulanodetal almenos certo?

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu sistema é PHP ou alguma otura tecnolgoia em que você trabalha só pelo sistema de arquivos - (isso é: seu único acesso ao servidor é por FTP, ou outra tecnologia para colocar arquivos lá) - o redirecionamento usando uma hresposta HTTP - 301 é a única forma de fazer isso mesmo.  (Mas nesse caso ainda é melhor usar uam resposta 301 de verdade do que um arquivo HTML estático com uma metatag para isso - em servidores de acesso limitado isso é possível com PHP ou um script CGI)

O DNS sempre vai apontar para um IP - (atualmente acredito que a maioria dos registros possa apontar simultâneamente para um IPv4 e um IPv6) - e o que resolve qual vai ser a raiz de um dado domínio é o seu servidor WEB que escuta nas portas 80 e 443 (em geral o Apache ou Nginx). Então se você tem acesso à configuração do servidor Web, você pode realizar a configuração que deseja.

A requisição HTTP chega ao servidor com a informação do domínio desejado - e a partir daí a configuração do mesmo pode modificar a requisição para que ela use internamente outra URL (e modificar os dados de saída para restaurar o domínio original).

Já que é uma URL complexa em outro sistema e não simplesmente um ponto específico com arquivos estáticos no filesystem, com o Apache você deve usar o [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

COm o Apache, é possível específicar regras de redirecionamento do modrewrite em arquivos `.htaccess` que você tem controle mesmo num servidor a que tenha acesso só ao filesystem. No entanto, a regra de rediressionamento tem que estar num arquivo `.htaccess`  localizado na raiz do domínio que voce quer redirecionar para a URL interna: sem acesso à configuração do servidor mesmo, a única forma de fazer isso é contratando uma conta separada para o outro domínio - e daí é melhor dar uma resposta HTTP 301 de qualquer forma. (já que nada garante que a segunda conta vai estar no mesmo IP e sendo servid pelo mesmo servidor que a primeira)

No Nginx, a funcionalidade do Mod_rewrite faz parte do núcleo da especificação de regras, e você pode ter uma idéia de por onde começar pela documentação oficial do mesmo -[mas aqui tem explicítos alguns exemplos de como fazer](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) um rewrite simples.

Lembrando que mesmo que você só tenha acesso ao filesystem, se você entender direitinho qual seria a regra de rewrite necessária no Apache/Nginx, deve ser possível solicitar ao seu ISP para colocar a regra pra você. Talvez tenha um custo extra - mas certamente vai ser menor do que contratar outra conta.

(Hoje em dia a maior parte das pessoas e -e as melhores tecnolgias para Web requerem - um sistema em que vocẽ tenha controle pelo menos ao nível de shell nesse caso seria possível criar um root separado para o outro domínio e escrever um `.htaccess` - mas melhor ainda é acesso a um VPS - em que você tem controle total inclusive do webserver)

Answer (score 1):

A resposta curta e grossa é: não tem como configurar isso no DNS.

Uma solução elegante é usar virtual hosts no servidor web.